# Can we close this question now?

Tags: discussion, closing

[What is the difference between a point and a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645672/what-is-the-difference-between-a-point-and-a-vector) is attracting a large number of content-free and/or repetitive answers, several from low-rep users. I think the signal-to-noise ratio won't be improved by leaving it open.

Comment: I flagged it to the moderators to protect it (user protection can only be placed after 48 hours or so). If it were me, I'd add a feature to auto-protect anything that goes on the hot questions list.

Answer (score 3):

For the general problem of

> A question is attracting a large number of content-free and/or repetitive answers, often from low-rep users.

The solution, as Asaf has indicated, is to

> Flag the question and ask for the question to be protected.

For more about protecting a question, see [this FAQ item on Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

Comment: I think that we should start collecting protection money. Or, you know, protection scotch.